# "\ /" in path error of ndk-build in Win7

Tags: eclipse, syntax, windows-7, path, android-ndk

Why does the \ / backslash frontslash occur in the path when I run ndk-build in my projects folder? Is that valid syntax?

I'm following the example in the book "Learning Android" by O'REILLY Marko Gargenta chapter 15. How to use the ndk-build command is not explaind "just do it!" And of course precisely that part fails mysteriously.

There is an Android.mk file in the jni folder. But I fail to target it for ndk-build.
I use ADT and NDK in Eclipse on Windows 7. <s>The \ / backslash frontslash in the error message below cannot be quoted here, I mark its place with !!!BACKSLASHFRONTSLASH!!!</s>

```
C:\Users\John\workspace\TestProject\>C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\android-ndk-r9c\ndk-build Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\John\workspace\/jni/Android.mk
C:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/android-ndk-r9c/build/core/add-application.mk:187: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

Comment: Using 4 spaces before a quoted line (piece of code) instead of > (quote) resolves the formatting issue with `\/`.

Comment: Now to address the problem in your `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT`, I would need to see your `jni/Application.mk`.